# How to obtain a list after sum over similar elements

Tags: java, list, arraylist, collections

**I have a list of Products class which has the following attributes:**

```
public class Products{
private int month;
private int year;
private int sku;
private String detail;
private Double quantity;
private Double price;
private Double discount;
private Double %discount;

    // getters and setters

static List<Products> sumProduct(List<Products> itemList) {
    
List<Product> tempListP = new ArrayList<Product>();

    Collections.sort(itemList, Comparator.comparing(Product::getYear)
            .thenComparing(Product::getMonth).thenComparing(Product::getSku));
    
    
    Integer itemCode = null; 
    double quantiti = 0;
    double price = 0;
    double discount = 0;
    double %discount = 0;
    Products itemObj = null;
    Integer itemMonth= null;
    Integer itemYear= null;
    
        for (int i = 0; i < itemList.size(); i++) {
            if (itemCode == null || (itemCode.equals(itemList.get(i).getSku())  && itemMonth.equals(itemList.get(i).getMonth()) && itemMonth.equals(itemList.get(i).getYear())  )) {
                quantiti = quantiti + itemList.get(i).getquantiti();
                price = price + itemList.get(i).getprice();
                discount = discount + itemList.get(i).getdiscount();
                %discount = %discount + itemList.get(i).get%discount();
                itemMonth = itemList.get(i).getMonth();
                itemYea = itemList.get(i).getYear();
            } else {
                
                itemObj = new Product( itemList.get(i).getMonth(), itemList.get(i).getYear(), itemCode, "" , quantiti, price,discount,%discount);
                
                
                if (tempListP.contains(itemObj)) {
                    tempListP.remove(itemObj);
                }
                tempListP.add(itemObj);
                quantiti = 0;
                quantiti = quantiti + itemList.get(i).getquantiti();
                price = 0;
                price = price + itemList.get(i).getprice();
                discount = 0;
                discount = discount + itemList.get(i).getdiscount();
                %discount = 0;
                %discount = %discount + itemList.get(i).get%discount();
                itemMonth = itemList.get(i).getMonth();
                itemYea = itemList.get(i).getYear();
            }

            itemCode = itemList.get(i).getSku();

            if (i == itemList.size() - 1) {
                itemObj = new Product( itemList.get(i).getMonth(), itemList.get(i).getYear(), itemCode, "" , quantiti, price,discount,%discount);
                tempListP.add(itemObj);
            }
        
        
    }
    

    return itemList;
}


}
```

**Main**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

   List<Products> items = new ArrayList<Products>();

   items.add(new Products(8,2020,10203040,"Tshirt",1,10.00,1.00,0.1));
   items.add(new Products(9,2020,10203040,"Tshirt",2,20.00,2.00,0.2));
   items.add(new Products(3,2021,10203040,"Tshirt",3,30.00,3.00,0.3));
   items.add(new Products(7,2020,50607080,"Tshirt",4,40.00,4.00,0.4));
   items.add(new Products(8,2020,10203040,"Tshirt",5,50.00,5.00,0.5));
   items.add(new Products(8,2021,10203040,"Tshirt",8,80.00,8.00,0.8));

  Products.sumProduct(items);
```

**Input**

```
Month | Year | Sku | Detail | Quantity | Price | Discount | % Discount

8 | 2020 | 10203040 | Tshirt | 1 | 10 | 1 | 0.1

9 | 2020 | 10203040 | Tshirt | 2 | 20 | 2 | 0.2

3 | 2021 | 10203040 | Tshirt | 3 | 30 | 3 | 0.3

7 | 2020 | 50607080 | Tshirt | 4 | 40 | 4 | 0.4

8 | 2020 | 10203040 | Tshirt | 5 | 50 | 5 | 0.5

8 | 2021 | 10203040 | Tshirt | 8 | 80 | 8 | 0.8
```

The final result should be like :

**Output:**

```
Month | Year | Sku | Detail | Quantity | Price | Discount | % Discount

7 | 2020 | 50607080 | Tshirt | 4 | 40 | 4 | 0.4

8 | 2020 | 10203040 | Tshirt | 6 | 60 | 6 | 0.6

9 | 2020 | 10203040 | Tshirt | 2 | 20 | 2 | 0.2

3 | 2021 | 10203040 | Tshirt | 3 | 30 | 3 | 0.3

8 | 2021 | 10203040 | Tshirt | 8 | 80 | 8 | 0.8
```

I would like to create a function that goes through a list of products and sum the value for the Items with the same month, year and sku, and return the list of sum of quantity, price, discount, %discount.

But how do I chain count and sum to the the above code? Especially for group by with more than 3 fields ( month, year and sku). Is there a better way to do this?

Really I need help to sum the values, not only is to group the elements in the list.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution should work, I wrote a comparator to sort the products. Then if consecutive items share the same values, sum the necessary values.

**Comparator**

```java
public class ProductsComparator implements Comparator<Products> {
    public int compare(Products p1, Products p2) {
        int value1 = p1.year.compareTo(p2.year);
        if (value1 == 0) {
            int value2 = p1.month.compareTo(p2.month);
            if (value2 == 0) {
                return p1.sku.compareTo(p2.sku);
            } else {
                return value2;
            }
        }
        return value1;
    }
}
```

**Sum Function**

```java
public static List<Products> sumProducts(List<Products> itemList) {
    List<Product> newList = new ArrayList<Product>();
    int index = -1;

    Collections.sort(itemList, new ProductsComparator());
     
    for(Products item : itemList){
        if(newList.size() != 0 && newList.get(index).getYear() == item.getYear() && newList.get(index).getMonth() == item.getMonth() && newList.get(index).getSku() == item.getSku()){
             // Add values
             newList.get(index).setquantiti(newList.get(index).getquantiti() +  item.getquantiti());
             newList.get(index).setprice(newList.get(index).getprice() +  item.getprice());
             newList.get(index).setdiscount(newList.get(index).getdiscount() +  item.getdiscount());
             newList.get(index).set%discount(newList.get(index).get%discount() +  item.get%discount());
        }else{
             newList.add(item);
             index++;
        }
    }

    return newList;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return those stats in a single return value you would ideally have structures with the values in them. This is a much better design that reusing the product class to contain an aggregate. That is overloading the use of class in a way that will be confusing to a reader.

This is a good use case for records as they do a lot of the work for you (e.g. defining `equals` and `hashCode` for your collation and aggregation). You can add some convenience functions to make the collation easier:

```
record MonthSKU(int month, int year, int sku) {
    MonthSKU(Product product) {
        this(product.month, product.year, product.sku);
    }
}

record ProductStats(double quantity, double price, double discount) {
    static ProductStats ZERO = new ProductStats(0, 0, 0);
    ProductStats(Product product) {
        this(product.quantity, product.price, product.discount);
    }
    ProductStats combine(ProductStats other) {
        return new ProductStats(quantity + other.quantity, price + other.price, discount + other.discount);
    }
}
```

Now using stream operators to group and sum is pretty trivial:

```
Map<MonthSKU,ProductStats> stats = productList.stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(MonthSKU::new, 
        reducing(ProductStats.ZERO, ProductStats::new, ProductStats::combine));
```

In my view this is a much more understandable model for your output statistics than a list of product containing aggregated values and an algorithm that requires a sorted list - this is both hard to understand and easy to break.

This model is also much easier to extend to add new fields or more sophisticated stats (such as maintaining a count to calculate averages). All those changes can be made just by changing the 2 records with no changes at all to the grouping and reducing operations.

On a similar note, the 'details' field seems to contain information related to the sku rather than the product. If so, you should have them in a separate `Map<Integer,String>` or a dedicated `SKU` class. If not, then you need to work out what to print in the aggregate summary when products have the same sku but different details.